# Customizing Django's contrib.auth views for password reset

Tags: python, django, django-views

Since Django 3.0, the django.contrib.auth views are class-based views. So when developing a password reset on a website, you would have to import do something like

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as av

av.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset_sent.html")
```

However, I want to add some custom features to my site like sending an email AFTER the password has been reset by the user. Where can I add my custom functions and how?

Note: I already configured an SMTP to my site and I also have the password reset setup with my custom templates.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to extend the `PasswordResetCompleteView` view and override the `get` method to send the email inside:

```py
class CustomPasswordResetCompleteView(PasswordResetCompleteView):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            # Send the email here... #
            super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done if you extends a class from `PasswordResetDoneView` as following:

```py
class MyPasswordResetDone(av.PasswordResetDoneView):
    def get(self, request, *args, ***kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Then you can do whatever you want in here.
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

I'm not sure if the best place to do it is in here or in `PasswordResetView` which has all the context and also the email of the user that is performing the action.

Take in account that in this view you don't have the email in the context at all. Then if you want the email of the user in this view you must change a little bit the `PasswordResetView` which I mentioned before.